# Jacobson radical of unitary subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This question is taken from "Graduate Course in Algebra for Martin Isaacs" which asking whether a statement is true or not.
The question says
if $S \subset R$ is a unitary subring (so it contains the same unity $1$ as in $R$), then determine whether the following statements is true or not:

(a) $J(S) \subset J(R)$

(b) $J(R) \cap S\subset J(S)$.

Here, $J(S)$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals in $R$.
So I think (a) is wrong because the passing the intersection reverse the inclusion, right?
I don't know if I am right and if so, is there a counterexample support this?

In (b), I believe it is true, as the inclusion reversed.

Comment: There is a nice characterization of elements in the Jacobson radical: $y \in J(R)$ if and only if $1 + xy$ is invertible for every $x \in R$. I haven't thought about this sort of thing in a while, but maybe that characterization might be  useful?  At least for the second one

Comment: Your conclusion for a) is right but the reason you gave seems incomprehensible.  Easy counterexamples would do the trick.  Any local domain that isn’t a field and its field of fractions would work.  Simply observing things about inclusions is not going to settle either one.

Comment: @PStheman so the second one is true and so it needs a proof, right?

Answer (score 1):

a) Consider any local domain $S$ with nonzero maximal ideal, and let $R$ its field of fractions.

b) Consider $S=F[x]$ and $R=F[x]_{(x)}$ ($F[x]$ localized at the prime ideal $(x)$).

Comment: so both statements not true?

Comment: @math_for_ever What do you think?  Work through them.

Comment: I see, $J(R)=(x)$, $J(S)=\{0\}$, right?

Comment: @math_for_ever It depends on which $R$ and $S$ you are talking about, and I don't know which one you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, I used your examples in b. $S=\mathbb{R}$ and $R=S_{(x)}$

Comment: @math_for_ever That's basically the right idea .You could even just demonstrate a single nonzero element of $J(R)\cap S$.